# How to tidy up call-finished screen?

Tags: calls, user-interface, ads

I have a Samsung Galaxy A21s running Android 11, One UI Core 3.1.

When I finish a phone call, all this crap shows up:

[image: fall-finished screen filled with a bunch of crap]

How do I get rid of all the stuff which is unrelated to the phone call?

- Create note/checklist
- Good morning
- Fact of the day
- Ads

I'm happy to see nothing or just return to the home screen. Ideally, I would be back in the phone dialer. How can I tidy this up?

Comment: Have you tried to install and use a different dialer app from Play Store? I would suspect that everything you dislike is caused by the Samsung dialer app installed on your phone.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd-party Phone app? Can you check it on the Settings - Apps & notifications - Advanced - Default apps? Otherwise,

Comment: If that crap is showing up full-screen, just tap the "recents" button to see which app it belongs to (in recents, the title will be shown). If it's the dialer app, replace it. If it's another app, disable/uninstall it. I could well imagine Samsung just added some "after-call app" (there are some such, to add notes etc as shown in your first image).